# Passenger apache default page error

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I just installed Passenger and the Passenger Pref Pane on OSX. However, when I try to browse to one of my Rails applications I just get the default Apache "it works!" page.

I've checked the vhost definitions and they seem ok so I can't seem to figure out whats wrong... I've tried reinstalling passenger and the pref pane and restarting apache but to no avail.

Anyone know how to fix this?

My vhost definition looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName boilinghot.local
  DocumentRoot "/Users/ganesh/Code/boilinghot/public"
  RailsEnv development
  <Directory "/Users/ganesh/Code/boilinghot/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer for this questions from SO. You can check it out here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719148/passenger-apache-default-page-error